# Chaining Association With Waterline

Tags: database, orm, sails.js, waterline

I have 3 models: feed, link and source.

Each feed has links with one-to-many association.

**Feed.js:**

```
links: {
    collection: 'link',
    via: 'feed'
}
```

And link model wired to the source model with one-to-one association.

**Link.js:**

```
source: {
    model: 'source'
}
```

And nothing special stuff in source model.

When I exec the query below, i can't get the details of links which are defined in source model.

```
Feed.find({}).populate('links').exec(console.log);
```

**Result:**

```
{
 links: 
 [
 {
    title: 'News link',
    url: 'http://href.com/sfs',
    feed: 1,
    source: 1,
    id: 1,
    createdAt: '2014-08-23T13:01:42.989Z',
    updatedAt: '2014-08-23T13:01:42.989Z'
}
],
title: 'Feed Title',
photo: 'img/img.png',
yesNo: false,
id: 1,
createdAt: '2014-08-23T13:00:43.317Z',
updatedAt: '2014-08-23T13:00:43.317Z' 
}
```

I want to populate "links" collection with source model. Is it possible with Waterline or do I have to do it manually?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waterline populations are currently only one level deep; multilevel populations are on the roadmap.  For the time being the best idea is to do your initial `Feed` query with links populated, gather up all of the `source` foreign keys from the `Link` records, find them all at once and then do a mapping.  Something like:

```
async.auto({

    // Get all feeds
    feeds: function(cb) {

        Feed.find({}).populate('links').exec(cb);

    },

    // Get all sources of feed links
    sources: ['feeds', function(cb, results) {

        var sourceIds = results.feeds.reduce(function(memo, feed) {

            return memo.concat(_.pluck(feed.links, 'source'));                       

        }, []);

        Source.find(sourceIds).exec(cb);

    }],

    // Map source objects onto links
    mapping: ['feeds', 'sources', function(cb, results) {

        // Index sources by ID
        var sources = _.indexBy(results.sources, 'id');

        var feeds = results.feeds.map(function(feed) {

            feed.links = feeds.links.map(function(link) {

                link.source = sources[link.source];
                return link;

            });

            return feed;

        });

        return cb(null, feeds);

    }]

}, function done(err, results) {

   // Handle err or do something with results.mapping

});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm too new on node/sails and need some working on this to understand. But it seems the best way for the time being. :)